# Is Assembly Circular Dependency a mistake in design

Tags: architecture, dependencies, dependency-management, circular-dependency

I have N application. each application at least include following assemblies:

- BusinessLogic
- DataAccess

In some scenarios application 1 needs to call a method from  BusinessLogic layer of application 2 and application 2 needs to call a method from businessLogic layer of application 1. this condition lead to assembly circular dependency between businessLogic layers of application 1 and application 2. I know it can lead to some problems in build process. now my question is: "Is it a mistake in architectural design? If yes, How to solve it?"

Answer (score 0):

If App2 has to call App1's Business Logic layer, that should be the red flag well before you get to circular dependency (because really that now business logic for app1 AND app2).

A common solution to this is exactly what you'd do when abstracting a base class in OOP languages. Find the pieces that are shared and move them out from underneath a single 'app', in this case, and put them in a library that can easily be shared across.

In your case, I'd grab the business logic operations that are share and put them in their own assembly that's named appropriately so both can consume it without issue.

Answer (score 0):

That simply tells you you might have to redesign your system. I would always avoid circular dependencies because you are mixing responsabilities and it will cause all kinds of problems later on.

Draw your components and relations and put each of them in their designated layer. Onion architecture is a great approach for designing your system and identifying all the assets, responsabilities and relations between them. Read [here](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) and [here](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-1/).

In your case you need a component that is used by both clients and that contains shared stuff. But based on the information you give us it's impossible to guess how.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have 2 assemblies mutually dependents (for example `System.dll` and `System.Configuration.dll` depends on each other in the .NET Fx). But as you might have experienced, you have to work hard against Visual Studio enforcement to avoid that.

Clearly **acyclic** dependencies between assemblies is a goal you **must** achieve. Else, your assemblies cannot be developed, compiled, and tested independently.

The common paradigm, is that `BusinessLogic` uses `DataAccess` and not the opposite. If you wish `DataAccess` to be able to call back `BusinessLogic` the usual way of doing so is:

- Define a call back interface in `DataAccess` assembly
- Implement this call back interface in `BusinessLogic` assembly (hence the `BusinessLogic` assembly references `DataAccess` assembly, but not the opposite)
- Pass one or several objects that implement this interface, from `BusinessLogic` to `DataAccess`, through a method defined in `DataAccess` that takes a call-back interface as parameter.

Having the `DataAccess` to be able to call back `BusinessLogic` is not a forbidden thing, but you should question yourself about why you want to do that, and you should try to limit these number of call-backs to a strict minimum.

---

Personally, I like to go further by consider namespaces in assembly as components, have acyclic namespace dependency, and avoiding to use the assembly artifact to define components. This is exposed in two white-books I authored, available [here](http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx).